# grid elements go outside the container on mobile version

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, grid

I am using MaterialUI Grid with React, and on phone dimensions my elements go off the screen, has someone faced a similar problem?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3VLJ.png)

Comment: You need to post your code, otherwise no one will be able to help you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.